# md-autocomplete not returning selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-material

I have implemented an md-autocomplete on my Angular.js site. The search and selecting works, It updates the shown list and everything. But for some reason I can't read the selected item. No matter how I define my md-selected-item it will always stay `null`. Both item in selectItem(item) and the value in the scope don't change.

AngularCode:

```
controllers.controller('UniSearch',function(SearchUniversity){
    var self = this;
    self.query = query;
    self.selectItem = selectItem;

    function query (searchText) {
        unis = SearchUniversity.get({ query : self.queryText });
        return unis.$promise.then(function(data) {
            var thing = [];
            // Just some code to reformat the data coming from the server
            angular.forEach(data,function(value,key){
                if (angular.isUndefined(value.UNI_ID)){
                    return
                }
                thing.push(value);
            });
            console.log(thing)
            return thing;
        });
    }

    function selectItem(item) {
        console.log(item);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div ng-controller="UniSearch as ctrl">
    <md-autocomplete
        md-selected-item="ctrl.selected"
        md-search-text="ctrl.queryText"
        md-items="uni in ctrl.query(queryText)"
        md-item-text="ctrl.selected.uni_international_name"
        md-autoselect="true"
        placeholder="Search for you city"
        md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectItem(item)">
        <md-item-template>
            <span md-highlight-text="queryText" md-highlight-flags="^i">
               {{uni.uni_international_name}}
            </span>
        </md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>
        No universities matching "{{ctrl.queryText}}" were found.
    </md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>

</div>
```

What am I missing? thx

Comment: There is any way to you put it on a fiddle or codepen to make easy to help?

Comment: I am having problems getting a fiddle to work. This is part of a relatively large codebase. Just wondering if there was anything obviously wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is hard to debug without run the code, but seem a little strange you enumarate the itens calling `uni` on `md-itens` call on onther functions by `item` specially at `md-selected-item`.

Comment: That worked. Wasn't expecting the name to matter in this instance.

Comment: Happy to help, so please, could you mark it as the right answer?

Comment: I never figured out what exactly Luiz meant above, but my answer was that md-selected-text and md-item-template needed to resolve to the same thing, so I effectively used `md-item-text="uni.uni_international_name"` and it worked for me.